# 100% Height Element Border Overlapping

Tags: html, css, border

I'm completely new to HTML/CSS, so I apologize if this is a rookie question. The following code has an inner element's border overlapping with the outer element's border if the height for both is set to 100%. The overlap occurs at the bottom.

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  border: 5px solid red;
}

p {
  text-align: center;
}

.body-content {
  border: 5px solid black;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  padding-left: 15px;
  padding-right: 15px;
  width: 50%;
}

.left-navbar {
  float: left;
  width: 5%;
  height: 100%;
  border: 5px solid pink;
  margin-bottom: -5px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
</head>

<body>
  <nav class="left-navbar">
    <p>test1</p>
    <p>test2</p>
    <p>test3</p>
  </nav>
  <div class="body-content">
    <article>
      <p>Content</p>
    </article>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

I attempted a negative margin / negative padding, but neither of those options had any effect. Is there some other way to manipulate the height of the element to take the 5px border into account? Finally, why is the negative margin/padding not having any effect?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make your `left-nav` a border box.

You can accomplish this by adding `box-sizing: border-box;`

It lets the browser include the vorders as part of the width and height;

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  border: 5px solid red;
}

p {
  text-align: center;
}

.body-content {
  border: 5px solid black;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  padding-left: 15px;
  padding-right: 15px;
  width: 50%;
}

.left-navbar {
  float: left;
  width: 5%;
  height: 100%;
  border: 5px solid pink;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
</head>

<body>
  <nav class="left-navbar">
    <p>test1</p>
    <p>test2</p>
    <p>test3</p>
  </nav>
  <div class="body-content">
    <article>
      <p>Content</p>
    </article>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: That was far simpler than I was expecting. I assume `box-sizing: border-box` basically flips the direction of the border towards the inside rather than the outside?

Comment: @ChrisAltig It lets the browser include the vorders as part of the width and height

Comment: @ChrisAltig anything else i might help you?

Comment: Nope, that's everything. Thank you so much for your assistance.